# Excel: OFFSET/TRANSPOSING to create a matrix of distances

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of ~90 locations and I need to calculate the eagle eye distance between these locations. I'm using the following formula to calculate the distance in miles:

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$F3))*COS(RADIANS(90-$F$2))+SIN(RADIANS(90-$F3))*SIN(RADIANS(90-$F$2))*COS(RADIANS($G3-$G$2)))*3958.756
```

[image: Sample]

The idea is that once I have all formulae for column H, I'd need just to drag columns to the right and have the new location fixed so that when in the matrix the Location matches itself, the distance will be zero.

I've been trying with TRANSPOSE and OFFSET without any success, any ideas?

Comment: Well, the simplest solution would be this: `IF(ROW()=COLUMN()-6,0,your_calculations)`. This assumes your top left cell of distance data is in `H2` and locations are in the same order on both lists.

Comment: I would make two new rows under the headers for cols H-K and copy the lats and longs to them (using paste special | transpose) - that will make life much easier.

Comment: I tried replacing that by `=IF(ROW()=COLUMN()-6,0,ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$F3))*COS(RADIANS(90-$F$2))+SIN(RADIANS(90-$F3))*SIN(RADIANS(90-$F$2))*COS(RADIANS($G3-$G$2)))*3958.756)` but it doesn't seem to work. I need to replace the second, fourth and fifth cell reference to the cell below when dragging to the right.

Comment: `INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(H$1,$E:$E))` gets the latitude value of the current column, `INDEX($G:$G,MATCH(H$1,$E:$E))` gets the longitude value.

Comment: @TomSharpe: That would solve my issue on the first row only, after that the cell references should be having an offset/transpose added formula when dragging down, which is the same issue I'm having in the first place, only transposed :)

Comment: The point is that you use a reference like $F5 and $G5 for the first location (having added two new rows), then H$3 and H$4 for the second location, then as you drag across and down these will adjust automatically by a combination of relative and absolute addressing.

Comment: I thought the problem is to get 0 on diagonal. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Enter

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>COLUMN(A1),ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$F2))*COS(RADIANS(90-INDEX($F$2:$F$5,COLUMN(A1))))+SIN(RADIANS(90-$F2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-INDEX($F$2:$F$5,COLUMN(A1))))*COS(RADIANS($G2-INDEX($G$2:$G$5,COLUMN(A1)))))*3958.756,"")
```

in `H2` (this cell will be empty) and copy/drag it to fill
the whole table `H2:K5` (some random `lon/lat`):

[image]

Here `ROW(A1)`, `COLUMN(A1)` is a lazy way to use `i,j` indices 
of the table element.

Just in case, the same formula in a structured form:

```
IF(
  ROW(A1)>COLUMN(A1),
  ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$F2))*COS(RADIANS(90-INDEX($F$2:$F$5,COLUMN(A1))))
    +SIN(RADIANS(90-$F2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-INDEX($F$2:$F$5,COLUMN(A1))))
    *COS(RADIANS($G2-INDEX($G$2:$G$5,COLUMN(A1)))))*3958.756,
  ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my suggestion

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-D$2))*COS(RADIANS(90-$B4))+SIN(RADIANS(90-D$2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-$B4))*COS(RADIANS(D$3-$C4)))*3958.756
```

[image]